# Binary variables constraint

Tags: linear-programming, constraint, binary-variable, logical-constraints

What constraints would you write to ensure that if $x = 1$ then $y = 0$ where $x, y$ are binary variables?

Until now I only learnt how to build the constraint with 3 binary variables, therefore the difficulty level of this task is very high for me.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/12102/755

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Via conjunctive normal form:
$$
x \implies \lnot y \\
\lnot x \lor \lnot y \\
(1 - x ) + (1 - y) \ge 1 \\
x + y \le 1
$$

Comment: what is the meaning of x + y <= 1 ? @RobPratt

Comment: @overboxed It is a linear inequality constraint that the binary decision variables  $x$ and $y$ are required to satisfy.  This constraint prevents $(x,y)=(1,1)$, which is the only solution that would violate the desired implication.